# Normalized to standard form in Rstudio

Tags: r

For Neural Network analysis, I normalized my data using the following function in R:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

weekends1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(weekends1, normalize))
```

Now that I have my desired result, how can I present my data as a standard form not normalized one?

Answer (score 0):

by standard you mean standard normal? Using the Mean Value Theorem, if your data are independent from the same distribution then  (x[i] - mean(x))/variance(x) follows a standard normal.

Comment: the output of my analysis is a plot with normalized values, however, I need to plot the result of neural network analysis with the initial values. For the neural network analysis, values should be normalized, but for my results, I need to show it using initial values. ( I am using a neural network to predict indoor temperature, Currently, I have the prediction in the range of 0-1, but I need to convert them to Celsius as it was initially to plot my results.